# Задан текст с помощью :after. Как можно убрать его на фон элемента которому он был задан?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как переместить серый текст **SERVICES** за текст **Awesome Services**?

```css
.services h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #DA0000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 145px 0 110px 0;
}

.services h2:after {
  content: "Services";
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #F8F8F8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 83px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container services">
  <h2>Awesome Services</h2>    
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/abWqmJK вот так наверно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задайте отрицательный `z-index` для псевдоэлемента `:after`

```css
.services h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #DA0000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 145px 0 110px 0;
}

.services h2:after {
  content: "Services";
  font-size: 150px;
  color: #F8F8F8;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 83px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container services">
  <h2>Awesome Services</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Забыл о существовании z-index...

Comment: @Holvender отметить решением не забываем